# How to know when a file has been created before it is renamed in VBA for Windows

Tags: excel, vba

I have had such a headache with this one, still not nailed.

I create a number of files using a VBA macro, renaming them as I go (this relates to PDF creation in an old version of Excel (2003), using an external PDF writer requiring the initial filename to be a default one, in case you were wondering)

I want the macro to wait until the file is created before attempting to rename it.  I then want the macro to wait until the file is renamed before creating another file.  This is not as easy as it sounds.  Attempts like Do While Dir(Filename)<>"" - Loop and Do While Dir(Filename)="" either generates Path file access error (again, the result of running ahead with itself - it works on resume) or locks the computer....

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Sub RenameIt(Cpy As String, CName As String)

    Do
    Loop Until Dir(Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\To Email.pdf") <> ""

    Name Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\To Email.pdf" As Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & _
    "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\" & CName & Cpy & ".pdf"

    Do While Dir(Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\To Email.pdf") <> ""
    Loop

End Sub
```

...creates the File Path Access error

```
Sub RenameIt(Cpy As String, CName As String)

    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        Err.Clear
        Do
        Loop Until Dir(Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\To Email.pdf") <> ""

        Name Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\To Email.pdf" As Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & _
        "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\" & CName & Cpy & ".pdf"

        Do While Dir(Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\To Email.pdf") <> ""
        Loop
    Loop Until Err.Number = 0

End Sub
```

... locks the computer after it has created the first file (not renamed)

Comment: How do you start the external PDF creator?

Comment: Hello there.  Thanks for your interest.  The PDF creator  (Bullzip) is installed as a printer, so the PDF is created by VBA as a regular print job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recap. The situation is that you start an asynchronous process that starts writing to a file, and you want to rename that file after the async process is done. However you do not know when that process is fully finished. It looks as if the print process creates the file and then starts writing to it. During this time the operating system keeps the file locked and it cannot be renamed.

Your current solutions do not test whether the `Name` operation succeeded. It will fail when the file is locked. You need to check this immediately after the operation.

```
Sub RenameIt(Cpy As String, CName As String)

  Do
    Wscript.Sleep 100
  Loop Until Dir(Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\To Email.pdf") <> ""

  Do
    Wscript.Sleep 100
    Name Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & _
         "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\To Email.pdf" _
      As Worksheets("Workpad").[b1] & _
         "NEW INVOICES\FOR EMAILING\" & CName & Cpy & ".pdf"
  Loop Until Err.Number = 0

End Sub
```

should do the trick. What this does is repeat until the file is no longer locked by the print process. It sleeps a negligible time for humans but long enough for computers, each iteration. You may also want to add a loop counter to ensure that the operation aborts with an error after a certain amount of time, instead of hanging.

Comment: Thanks for your help